# express-session not sending cookie to browser in deployment

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm using vercel for hosting this nodejs app.

### Express-session

here is the session declarement and some other middlewares

```
let store = new mongoDBStoreSession({
    uri: process.env.MONGO_URI,
    collection: 'mySessions'
});

store.on('error', function(error) {
console.log(error);
});

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
    credentials: true
}))

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.set("trust proxy", 1)

app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    store: store,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false
    cookie: {
        secure: true, // i set it false for localhost server
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10, // 10 Minutes
        sameSite: "none"
    }
}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5173");
    next();
})
```

### Frontend api call

This is how I call the api from my website.
I cannot access /chat after succesfully logged in, because there is no cookies saved in the browser.

```
axios.post(`${api}/user/login`, inputJson, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      withCredentials: true, 
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          throw new Error('Request failed, status ' + response.status);
        }
        console.log(response.data);
        // window.location.href = "/chat";
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

from localhost server, the api works fine, and my website can access the protected /chat route because the browser has cookie contains the login session.

Then I deploy the app to vercel, the api is working, my website receives logged in message but didn't receive any cookie when logging in, it causes I cannot access the protected /chat route.

I tried using postman and insomnia to access the vercel app, it works normal, I receive the cookie when logging in, and can access the protected route with that cookie.

Node version: 18.17.0  Express-session: 1.17.3  Express: 4.18.2